# Как убрать размытость текста в phpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, шрифты, mac

Перешел с винды на мак и обнаружил что текст во всем phpStorm слегка размыт(в сравнении с виндой), а в редакторе он еще и жирнее.

Подскажите как убрать эту мутность? Или посоветуйте шрифт не такой мутный.

[image: Шрифт на phpStorm Винде]
[image: Шрифт на phpStorm Маке]

Comment: однозначного ответа нет. Можно попробовать поиграть с настройками **Antialiasing** в **Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance** - см. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.3/appearance.html. Если не поможет, попробуйте ключ `lcd.contrast.value` (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-142003#comment=27-1552390). Ну еще можно попробовать другую версию Java (скачать с сайта Oracle, например - вдруг она в вашем случае лучше справится с отображение шрифтов, чем это делает bundled JDK)